# Choosing a line such that a given polynomial does not vanish

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the polynomial $p(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_j(2 \pi i z)^n$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$.

I need to find a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that this polynomial does not vanish on the line $\{z: z=x+ic, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$

However I'm having difficulties approaching this problem especially since the choice of constants are arbitrary. Any help is appreciated.

An idea I had was to use the argument principle: take a rectangular contour surrounding some line segment as above ( to allow endpoints to go to infinity later).  The integral of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}ja_j(2 \pi i z)^{j-1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j(2 \pi i z)^{j-1}}$ along the sides perpendicular to the line cancel each other out, so let those go to zero.  We're left with two sides parallel to the line with opposite orientation.  As $p(z)$ does not have any poles, we want the integral of the contour to be zero, so we'd pick a suitable line. However, this doesn't seem to help us find an appropriate line so I'm stuck.

Note that this is in Stein's Complex Analysis, a problem in chapter 4 (brief overview of fourier analysis in relation to complex analysis)

Comment: If $|z|$ is so large that the term in $z^n$ is bigger than the rest of the terms put together, then the polynomial can't be zero. So you just have to choose $c$ large enough for this to happen.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you , I see now.  I'll try it out.